# How to change the grey background with a film icon on html5 video in android Webview

Tags: android, video, background, webview

I'm developing an android app which load a website via webview, everything works fine and the video can play.

However, the video when in idle state show a grey background and a film icon in center, when in loading state it show a grey background and a loading icon. It doesn't suit with my website, so i want to change it color to black, or if possible, change it into some image.

How can i do it?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate question as I can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271991/html5-video-remove-overlay-play-icon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 video remove overlay play icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271991/html5-video-remove-overlay-play-icon)