# HTML5 video remove overlay play icon

Tags: android, android-webview, html5-video

How do I remove the overlay play icon (triangle) that's visible in the center of the video for a second or so every time a video starts playing in an Android WebView?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm using [html5webview](https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/). For a complete compilable project, see surendra's answer in [WebView and and HTML5 <video>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video).

I'm testing on Android 4.1 Jelly Bean, Sony Xperia Tablet Z to be specific

Comment: It's the same on Google Nexus 7 by Asus.

Comment: If I understand correctly, simply adding a "poster" attribute pointing to a 1x1 transparent png file would do the trick :)

Answer (score 28):

If you said about this picture [image]

This is picture I had when tested my app on Android 6.0.

You can hide this picture. For example:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientCustomPoster());
```

Chrome client class:

```
private class WebChromeClientCustomPoster extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
}
```

More info read [api](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#getDefaultVideoPoster())

Comment: Hi! I'm getting error when cast WebChromeClientCustomPoster class to WebChromeClient.

WebView webView = (WebView)appView.getEngine().getView();
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientCustomPoster());

How can I solve this issue.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: i did the same but still issue is there. Not resolved issue.

Comment: This is the import line needed: `import android.graphics.Bitmap;`

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution.
Just add the 'poster' attribute.

e.g. `poster="https://via.placeholder.com/1x1"` or `poster="noposter"`

Note: Empty value are ignored. (`poster=""`)

Answer (score 2):

Please note that setting `poster` to an invalid URL (such as "noposter") might trigger a network call and an `error` event from the video player.

In my projects, I'm setting the poster to a [tiny transparent GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13139830/1795244):

`poster="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"`

Comment: This is exactly the best answer. It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Neither `poster="noposter"` nor `poster="null"` work for me.

I made it work by creating a placeholder image that has just a white background color and assigned it to the video per DOM.

```
document.getElementById("myVideo").poster = "noposter.png";
```