# Hide Native Android HTML5 Video Play Button in CSS

Tags: android, css, html, video, html5-video

On iOS I can simply remove the play button by doing

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
  display: none !important;
}
```

However, on Android (using version 7.0) I can't remove the play button when trying the following.

`video::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-play-button`

`video::-webkit-media-controls`

`video::--webkit-media-controls-play-button`

Here's my video element: `<video autoplay muted></video>`

I could solve this natively, as shown here [HTML5 video remove overlay play icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271991/html5-video-remove-overlay-play-icon), but I'd prefer to do a CSS solution if possible.

For reference, this is what the Android play button looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this question, an alternative solution to the native one is to simply **not** include `android-webview-video-poster:` in your Content Security Policy. This will block the image from ever loading in the first place. Not sure if this is considered a hackish solution, but it seems to work for me.

Comment: Definitely a hackish solution. I'm not comfortable possibly nuking my application from messing with CSP headers to accomplish this. Unfortunately I have to downvote this as it's not a CSS solution which is what the OP asks for.

Comment: Understandable, everyone is entitled to their opinions. However, I am actually the OP and this is the only non-native way to do it, as far as I know.

Comment: Is there a specific meta tag that only removes this image? When I try this it removes the play button but also breaks a bunch of other assets in the app